# Django-simple-captcha Play Captcha Audio In Browser Not In Downloaded .wav File

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, captcha

By default, django-simple-captcha uses the flite linux command line program to convert the captcha text into a downloadable .wav file when a user clicks on the captcha image. Instead of downloading .wav files, a better user experience would be to play the audio directly in the browser by clicking a play button.

How would one go about changing the default behavior of django-simple-captcha to do this? Is there a way to get it to universally work across many different forms such as template forms, allauth forms, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use html5's <audio> tags. Dropping the link for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp. This is what I did:

**forms.py**

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField, CaptchaTextInput
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms import ModelForm

User = get_user_model()

class CustomCaptchaTextInput(CaptchaTextInput):
    template_name = "register/custom.captcha.html"

class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField(
        label = "Captcha",
        label_suffix = "",
        widget = CustomCaptchaTextInput(
            attrs = {"class": "form-field"}
        )
    )
    username = forms.CharField(
        label = "Username",
        label_suffix = "",
        required = True,
        help_text = "",
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {"class": "form-field"}
        )
    )
    
    email = forms.CharField(
        label = "Email",
        label_suffix = "",
        max_length = 100,
        required = True,
        help_text = "",
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {"class": "form-field"}
        )
    )
    
    password = forms.CharField(
        label = "Password",
        label_suffix = "",
        required = True,
        help_text = "",
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs = {"class": "form-field"}
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password"]
```

In my forms.py file I created a custom class that inherits from CaptchaTextInput and override the template_name variable with my own custom template file. Next, I set the widget in my RegisterForm's captcha field to point to this customized class. Note that you will get a template not found error if you do not use the naming scheme app/your_template_name.html or in my case register/custom.captcha.html for the template_name. To make it clearer my custom file is in register/templates/register/custom.captcha.html

**custom.captcha.html**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if audio %}
        <audio id="captcha-audio"src="{{ audio }}" type="audio/wav"></audio>
        <a title="{% trans "Play CAPTCHA as audio file" %}">
    {% endif %}
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="captcha" class="captcha" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha-audio').play()" />
    {% if audio %}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% include "django/forms/widgets/multiwidget.html" %}
```

For reference, this was the original Django-Simple-Captcha code for this file: https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/blob/master/captcha/templates/captcha/widgets/captcha.html. In my custom captcha.html file I copied the contents from the original file and made a few modifications. I included the <audio> tags with an ID name so that later I can click on the captcha image and play the sound via onclick. I also moved the template tag {{ audio }} to the html5 <audio> tags.